# label median values of boxplot in R

Tags: r, time-series, boxplot

I have plotted a `boxplot` for timeseries data with freq=12 in R. I want R to display median values in `boxplot` for every month. How would I do that?

R code:

```
st_ts = ts(stocks[,2],start = c(2000,4),end = c(2015,10),frequency = 12)
boxplot(st_ts ~ cycle(st_ts))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here with ggplot

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(abs = as.factor(rep(1:12, 10)), ord = rnorm(120, 5, 1))

calcmed <- function(x) {
   return(c(y = 8, label = round(median(x), 1)))
   # modify 8 to suit your needs
}

ggplot(data, aes(abs, ord)) +
     geom_boxplot() +
     stat_summary(fun.data = calcmed, geom = "text") +
     #annotate("text", x = 1.4, y = 8.3, label = "median :") +
     xlab("Abs") +
     ylab("Ord") +
     ggtitle("Boxplot")
```

[image: sample]

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547448/r-for-the-same-code-labels-q1-median-appear-on-one-computer-but-dont-appea thanks